# Apache ignite client node reconnect getting error org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheStoppedException: Failed to perform cache operation

Tags: ignite

I have started ignite server as well as app as client node using the following configuration

```
public IgniteConfigurer config() {
return cfg -> {
    // The node will be started as a client node.
    cfg.setClientMode(true);
    // Classes of custom Java logic will be transferred over the wire from this app.
    cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(false);
    // Setting up an IP Finder to ensure the client can locate the servers.
    final TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
    ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList(ip));
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(ipFinder));
    // Cache Metrics log frequency. If 0 then log print disable.
    cfg.setMetricsLogFrequency(Integer.parseInt(cacheMetricsLogFrequency));
    // setting up storage configuration
    final DataStorageConfiguration storageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();
    storageCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    storageCfg.setStoragePath(cacheStorage);
    // setting up data region for storage
    final DataRegionConfiguration defaultRegion = new DataRegionConfiguration();
    defaultRegion.setName(cacheDefaultRegionName);
    // Sets initial memory region size. When the used memory size exceeds this value, new chunks of memory will be allocated
    defaultRegion.setInitialSize(Long.parseLong(cacheRegionInitSize));
    storageCfg.setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(defaultRegion);
    cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(storageCfg);
    cfg.setWorkDirectory(cacheStorage);
    final TcpCommunicationSpi communicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
    // Sets message queue limit for incoming and outgoing messages
    communicationSpi.setMessageQueueLimit(Integer.parseInt(cacheTcpCommunicationSpiMessageQueueLimit));
    cfg.setCommunicationSpi(communicationSpi);
    final CacheCheckpointSpi cpSpi = new CacheCheckpointSpi();
    cfg.setCheckpointSpi(cpSpi);
    final FifoQueueCollisionSpi colSpi = new FifoQueueCollisionSpi();
    // Execute all jobs sequentially by setting parallel job number to 1.
    colSpi.setParallelJobsNumber(Integer.parseInt(cacheParallelJobs));
    cfg.setCollisionSpi(colSpi);
    // set failure handler for auto connection if ignite server stop/starts.
    cfg.setFailureHandler(new StopNodeFailureHandler());
};
```

}

everything working fine. Now I have stopped ignite server and again restart ignite server. After restarting ignite server When I do any cache operation on I am getting error like

```
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheStoppedException: Failed to perform cache operation (cache is stopped): mycache1
... 63 more
```

When I see ignite server logs it shows me the client is connected. See below logs

```
[17:25:41]   ^-- Baseline [id=0, size=1, online=1, offline=0]
[17:25:42] Topology snapshot [ver=2, locNode=ea964803, servers=1, clients=1, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=8, offheap=6.3GB, heap=4.5GB]
[17:25:42]   ^-- Baseline [id=0, size=1, online=1, offline=0]
```

So why it not allowed to perform any cache operation through the application which is running as a client node?.

Comment: Which Ignite version are you using? Works fine for me with the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating your `"mycache1"` inside the default data region which is not configured to be persistent.

I.e. you first define a default region to be persistent:

```
storageCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
storageCfg.setStoragePath(cacheStorage);
```

But further you are re-creating it **without** setPersistenceEnabled:

```
    final DataRegionConfiguration defaultRegion = new DataRegionConfiguration();
    defaultRegion.setName(cacheDefaultRegionName);
    // Sets initial memory region size. When the used memory size exceeds this value, new chunks of memory will be allocated
    defaultRegion.setInitialSize(Long.parseLong(cacheRegionInitSize));
    storageCfg.setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(defaultRegion);
```

So you need to replace `getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` with `storageCfg.setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(defaultRegion);` to enable persistence and I think you won't have `CacheStoppedException` anymore.

As for in-memory configuration (which I think was applied here instead) and dynamically created caches, this is expected behavior. Because in this case, the server knows nothing about the previously created caches and you need to recreate them explicitly. Doing something like:

```
try{

... 
}
catch(Exception exception) {
  if (exception instanceof IgniteException) {
  final Throwable rootCause = getRootCause(exception);

  if(rootCause instanceof CacheStoppedException)
  {
    ignite.cache("mycache1");
    mylogger.info("Connection re-estabilished with the cache.");
  }
}
```